# Trying to understand CMTime

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, cmtime

I have seen some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808557/avassetwriterinputpixelbufferadaptor-and-cmtime) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396800/help-me-understand-cmtime-in-avassetwriter) [CMTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake) (Three separate links), but I still don't get it. I'm using an AVCaptureSession with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and I want to set the max and min frame rate of the the output. My problem is I just don't understand the CMTime struct.

Apparently CMTimeMake(value, timeScale) should give me value frames every 1/timeScale seconds for a total of value/timeScale seconds, or am I getting that wrong?

Why isn't this documented anywhere in order to explain what this does?

If it does truly work like that, how would I get it to have an indefinite number of frames?

If its really simple, I'm sorry, but nothing has clicked just yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to understand CMTime and CMTimeMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake)

Comment: https://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime

Answer (score 188, accepted):

A `CMTime` struct represents a length of time that is stored as rational number (see [CMTime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html)). `CMTime` has a `value` and a `timescale` field, and represents the time `value/timescale seconds` .

`CMTimeMake` is a function that returns a `CMTime` structure, for example:

```
CMTime t1 = CMTimeMake(1, 10); // 1/10 second = 0.1 second
CMTime t2 = CMTimeMake(2, 1);  // 2 seconds
CMTime t3 = CMTimeMake(3, 4);  // 3/4 second = 0.75 second
CMTime t4 = CMTimeMake(6, 8);  // 6/8 second = 0.75 second
```

The last two time values `t3` and `t4` represent the same time value, therefore

```
CMTimeCompare(t3, t4) == 0
```

If you set the `videoMinFrameDuration` of a `AVCaptureSession` is does not make a difference if you set

```
connection.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 20); // or
connection.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(2, 40);
```

In both cases the minimum time interval between frames is set to 1/20 = 0.05 seconds.

Comment: How to convert 3 seconds to CMTime?

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa: `CMTimeMake(3, 1)`

Comment: Well explained... :-)

Comment: Please help me with that: I have the `current time` of video when playing, and how to get the `number of frame` in that time?

Comment: @MartinR Is it possible achieve the desired result using `addPeriodicTimeObserver` ? many thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704885

Comment: @MartinR Why not just a fixed decimal number? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ricardo: What exactly do you suggest?

Comment: @MartinR It is just a question. What is the reason of using CMTime? Perhaps using a number with a lot of decimals? Would be possible to use NSDecimalNumber?

Answer (score 5):

My experience differs.

For `let testTime = CMTime(seconds: 3.83, preferredTimescale: 100)`

If you set a breakpoint and look in the debugger side window it says:

"383 100ths of a second"

Testing by seeking to a fixed offset in a video in AVPlayer has confirmed this.

So put the actual number of seconds in the seconds field, and the precision in the preferredTimescale field. So 100 means precision of hundredths of a second.

Doing
`let testTime = CMTime(seconds: 3.83, preferredTimescale: 100)`

Still seeks to the same place in the video, but it displays in the debugger side window as "3833 1000ths of a second"

Doing
`let testTime = CMTime(seconds: 3.83, preferredTimescale: 1)`

Does not seek to the same place in the video, because it's been truncated, and it displays in the debugger side window as "3 seconds". Notice that the .833 part has been lost due to the preferredTimescale.

Answer (score 0):

```
CMTime(seconds: value, timescale: scale)
```

means value/scale in a just one second