# Is presenting a video feed faster with GPUImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-capture, gpuimage

I need to get video from the iPhone camera and present it to the user (I do some UIView overlays) Do I get more FPS with GPUImage *without* any post processing?

Thanks

Comment: As compared to AV Foundation? No. Both will present raw camera data to the screen at the same framerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brad Larson** in discussion forum for `GPUImage` on [GitHub](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1207):

> "I don't know of any hard limit for framerate internally, unless you're rendering to the screen at some point. The screen might cap a refresh rate at 60 FPS when presenting the render buffer. This could potentially pause the OpenGL ES queue at that point if rendering faster than 60 FPS."

[Here](http://nshipster.com/gpuimage/) is a nice article on `GPUImage`. Don't forget that the FPS will var between various iPhone types.

Plus, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330174/avcapture-capturing-and-getting-framebuffer-at-60-fps-in-ios-7) out on SO.