# Captured video with AVAssetWriter have duration zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm trying to capture video with `AVAssetWriter`, `AVCaptureSession`, `AVCaptureOutput` and `AVAssetWriterInput`.

Here is delegate method for `AVCaptureOutput` where I'm adding buffers:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {


    if (self.assetWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusWriting) {

        CMTime startTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);

        [self.assetWriter startWriting];

        [self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:startTime];
    }
    if ([captureOutput isKindOfClass:AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.class] && self.videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {

        [self.videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    }
    else if ([captureOutput isKindOfClass:AVCaptureAudioDataOutput.class] && self.audioWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {

        [self.audioWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    }
}
```

And method for finishing writing:

```
- (void)finishCurrentWriting {

    [self.videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
    [self.audioWriterInput markAsFinished];

    __weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;

    [self.assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [weakSelf runVideo];
        });
    }]; 
}
```

When I'm ending writing video into file, I'm trying to play it via `MPMoviePlayerController`. The data is available because file have significant size, but for some reasons, the duration of video is zero. What am I doing wrong?

Added [repository](https://github.com/VasylKhmil/AVAssetWriterExample) with test code. It is for HLS streaming, so for now it should make 15s videos and after that display it in player on bottom of screen(now player is just black, and video duration is 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to call `[AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:]` when you've finished.

You should be calling `startSessionAtSourceTime` with presentation time stamp of the first buffer you receive.

You can delete the `[self.assetWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];`
.

Comment: Updated question with more info, any other suggestions?

Comment: added some suggestions

Comment: Can you put up a small example on github?

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.assetWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

You are setting the session end time to zero, making the recording 0 seconds long...

Comment: And what should I set there? Lets say, I have NSTimeInterval value with video duration.

Comment: This depends on your fps and duration. [Look here for some explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13001917/312312) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001755/trying-to-understand-cmtime-and-cmtimemake)