# Set start time AVUrlAsset using CMTime for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to merge an audio in video but this custom audio does not necessarily from the beginning. The user listens for a music and then if the user feels like want to start the video recording, the user will tap on a button that starts the video recording while the music is playing.

So the user could start after 20 or 32 seconds after the audio started.

I have no problem in merging, but my problem is understanding how to set the CMTimeRange.Start using CMTime for my audio background.

The Start time value is a .NET's TimeSpan, now for example the user started after 32 seconds

var startTime = new TimeSpan(0,0,32);

or the user started after 53 seconds and then starts the video recording.

how do you translate this to CMTime?

Comment: Hi, have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, we get the seconds From `TimeSpan` by using

```
TimeSpan span;
double time = span.TotalSeconds
```

Then ,we have to understand `CMTime`  and how to translate float values to it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13001917/8187800) you can refer to .

CMTime has a `value` and a `timescale` field, and `time = value/timescale` .