# addPeriodicTimeObserver is not called every millisecond?

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I know that `player.currentItem.currentTime().seconds` returns the current time in seconds of the audio file that is being played.

Can I add a callback function on `player` to be called every millisecond?
For example for second 1, this callBack function should be called 1000 times.

The problem is that using `addPeriodicTimeObserver` the callBack function is called only 1 time per second, rather than 1000 times per second.

**Why do I need this?**

**1.**
I am extracting the beat count of a Salsa song manually by tapping on a button in the UI while the audio file is being played and I record it as `[Int:Int]` // *milisecondButtonTapped: beatCount.*

My array is going to look like
`var beatCounts = [982: 1, 2051: 2, 3006: 3, 5027: 5, 6011: 6, 7028: 7]`

After the audio finishes playing I will end up with an array containing the beatCounts corresponding to certain milliseconds of `player.currentItem.currentTime()`

**2.**

Now, I want to play the song again and check if player currentTime in milliseconds is == to one of the values in `var beatCounts`

```
func checkCurrentTime(playerTimeMilliseconds: Int) {

  for (millisecond, beatCount) in beatCounts {
    if  playerTimeMilliseconds == millisecond {
       //show beatCount in label on UI 
     }
 }
}





func playSound(url: URL) {

    let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)


    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    player?.play()

    player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1000), queue: DispatchQueue.main, using: { [weak self] (CMTime) in

        print("cmtime is \(CMTime)")
      CMTime.value

        if self?.player?.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {

        }
    })

}//end playSound
```

Comment: I think it is called for each second.

Comment: Check the official reference of [addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval:queue:using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385829-addperiodictimeobserver). You can use `1/1000` for your seconds parameter.

Comment: @nayem please see `func playSound(url: URL)` in my original question. That's what I am doing already, but the block is called only 1 time per second

Comment: Well, you might have not gone to the link I provided. There is a sample in the **Discussion** section. You should not consider `preferredTimescale` to be the divisor of the second.

Comment: Note that `CMTime` is a CoreMedia type you should rename it to `time` inside your closure. `using: { [weak self] time in` and then `print("CMTime:", time)`

Comment: @LeoDabus you posted a comment previously with a solution, but I see that you deleted it. It was something related to `CMTimeMake` Can you post that again

Comment: `CMTime(seconds: 0.01, preferredTimescale: 1)`

Comment: @LeoDab It is not firing the callback. Please see gist
       https://gist.github.com/bibscy/d5ca0b9b0ed465b83baa493a4e77f98e

Comment: I would not use it with a repeating interval of 100 times per second, make it 2 or 3 times per second. Why would you need to update the UI 100/1000 times per second?

Comment: Because initially I record the beatCount manually, and every time I tap on a button in the UI, I will record the millisecond when the button it tapped. Later on when I play the song I want to compare the the milliseconds recorded against the milliseconds of the currentItem played and display the beatCount in a label. In `func addPeriodicTimeObserver()` even if I use `let interval = CMTime(seconds: 0.5,
                              preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))` it still does not work

Comment: I just took a look at the gist you provided. Why on earth would you think that adding periodic observer to another player (`player2` in your case) would fire when you are playing the item with `player`?

Comment: @nayem You're right, it makes no sense. However, `var player` is of type `AVAudioPlayer`. Calling `addPeriodicTimeObserver ` on `player` will return an error since it is not a method of this class. How do I go around it?

Comment: ___Calling `addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval:queue:using:)` on player (`AVAudioPlayer `) will return an error___ - actually you can't even call this. Why don't you play your file with the instance of `AVPlayer`? Get rid of the `AVAudioPlayer` instance.

Comment: I am trying to play now the file with instance of AVPlayer, but it does not output any sound and no error is thrown either    `func addPeriodicTimeObserver(url: URL) {
      
      
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
      
        player.play()
    }`

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use forInterval differently, whereas time unit will be 0.001 and preferred time scaled should be used with NSEC_PER_SEC as quoted below

*let interval: CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.001, preferredTimescale:  Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC))*

```
player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: *interval*), queue:
.main) { [weak self] (CMTime) in
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers